# How to prove that work due to conservative forces are independent of path?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, work, potential-energy, conservative-field

The Wikipedia article on conservative forces says,

> A force field F, defined everywhere in space (or within a simply-connected volume of space), is called a conservative force or conservative vector field if it meets any of these three equivalent conditions: [...] 3. The force can be written as the negative gradient of a potential,
> $\Phi$: $\vec F = - \vec \nabla \Phi$.

*Source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservative_force*

I don't understand why $\Phi$ having spatial derivatives equal to $\vec F$'s components implies that the work done by the force $W = -\Delta \Phi$ is independent of the path a test particle takes.

Comment: Does not the next section of the Wikipedia article answer your question?

Comment: perhaps look at the fundamental theorem of calculus for line integrals which tells you that the line integral of the gradient of a scalar depends only on the end points. It's not really anything about having "spatial derivatives" it's more about how F be written in terms of what derivatives. as curl, gradient, divergence, etc. are all different ways of differentiating--each with different properties.